# Elixir zero hour time as 24

Tags: erlang, elixir

I need to convert an erlang time stamp to NaiveDateTime in elixir.

```
  NaiveDateTime.from_erl {{2019, 4, 24}, {24, 0, 0}}
  {:error, :invalid_time}
```

The docs for NaiveDateTime (and all other time modules in elixir) do not support 24 as the zero time even through it is ISO8601 compatible.

Any ideas on how to deal with this?  I could pattern match on the tuple and then just change it to 0, but I feel that is a pretty ugly solution. Any ideas?

Thanks

*Update* 
My solution: Thanks to @Aleksei Matiushkin with a tweak.

```
defmodule Helpers do
    def naive_date_time({{y, m, d}, {24, 0, 0}}) do    
       case NaiveDateTime.from_erl({{y, m, d}, {0, 0, 0}}) do
           {:ok, naive_dt} -> {:ok, NaiveDateTime.add(naive_dt, 24 * 3_600)}
           {:error, reason} -> {:error, reason}
       end
    end
    def naive_date_time(dt), do: NaiveDateTime.from_erl(dt)
  end
```

Comment: Where do you get this tuple from in the first place?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin From the ODBC driver! Its coming from a database call and then gets mapped to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation clearly states [this format is not supported](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/NaiveDateTime.html#from_iso8601/2):

> while ISO 8601 allows datetimes to specify 24:00:00 as the zero hour of the next day, this notation is not supported by Elixir

That said, one should not expect this to be handled even in the future. I would go with an explicit helper function:

```rb
defmodule Helpers do
  def naive_date_time({{y, m, d}, {24, 0, 0}}),
    do: NaiveDateTime.add({{y, m, d}, {0, 0, 0}}, 24 * 3_600)
  def naive_date_time(dt), do: NaiveDateTime.from_erl(dt)
end
```

I do not see any ugliness here. Please note, one should *add* a day when converting `{24, 0, 0}` → `{0, 0, 0}`.

---

**NB!** the solution above raises on malformed input. See the update in the original question for the fix, or below:

```rb
defmodule Helpers do
  def naive_date_time({{y, m, d}, {24, 0, 0}}) do    
    {{y, m, d}, {0, 0, 0}}
    |> NaiveDateTime.from_erl()
    |> naive_date_time_add()
  end
  def naive_date_time(dt), do: NaiveDateTime.from_erl(dt)

  defp naive_date_time_add({:ok, dt}),
    do: {:ok, NaiveDateTime.add(dt, 24 * 3_600)}
  defp naive_date_time_add(err), do: err
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it wasn't supported from the docs, just didn't know if anyone had a good solution. Thanks for your helper! Thanks

Comment: See my tweak in the answer. This technically doesn't work. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, indeed. For some reason, I thought [`NaiveDateTime.add/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/NaiveDateTime.html#add/3) returns `{:error, reason}` tuple, not raises, on malformed input. I updated the answer to point to your fix.